# Is there some tool/command to run azcli files from powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I'm using VS Code, and to get some intellisense when writing the azure cli script I've put everything in a `.azcli` file. My question now is how do I execute that file from a powershell terminal? Also, is it possible to use parameters in such a script like:

```
az servicebus topic create -g $resourceGroup -n $topicName --namespace-name $namespace
```

Is it possible to call a `azcli` file that looks like the one above and provice the `$resourceGroup, $topicName, $namespace` as argument from powershell?

Comment: Do something like `iex (gc .\myfile.azcli -Raw)`?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of an easy way to do this in PowerShell. If someone knows, I would like to know as well.

If you have [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) installed, you can run `.azcli` files just like `.sh` shell scripts inside WSL from PowerShell. WSL will need to have Azure CLI installed as well, so depending on the distribution you pick(Ubuntu or Debian are ussually safe), you will need to follow the instructions from [Install the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

To run script in WSL from PowerShell terminal:

```
bash -c "./file.azcli"
```

Or directly in WSL terminal:

```
./file.azcli
```

You can use parameters in a `.azcli` file just like `.sh` shell scripts:

```
resourceGroup=MyRG
topicName=MyTopicName
namespace=myNameSpaceName

az servicebus topic create -g $resourceGroup -n $topicName --namespace-name $namespace
```

You could also create a `.vscode/tasks.json`, similar to what this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurecli/issues/32) recommends.